# Are there any Node.js modules that provide fuzzy date strings?

Tags: javascript, date, time, node.js

I'm thinking of strings like "one minute ago" or "3 weeks ago", that kind of thing.

I could easily port examples I've found in other languages but there's no need to reinvent the wheel if this stuff is already out there.

Comment: [This might help](http://webdesign.onyou.ch/2010/08/04/javascript-time-ago-pretty-date/). Shows you a fuzzy date based on the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you can try is date.js: http://www.datejs.com/

To make it node compatible at the very bottom of the script add the line:

`module.exports = Date;`

Then you can require it:

`var date = require('./date');`

Assuming date.js is in the same folder, otherwise modify the require path.

Then a simple code sample to test is:

`console.log( date.today().next().thursday() )`

Comment: Looks like someone's already done that and published it as a Node package available via npm (npm install datejs).

Comment: Ha doesn't get better than that :D

Comment: Neither `npm install datejs` not using a modified datejs directly work as advertised in Node v0.4.7

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a library called [moment](https://github.com/timrwood/moment) that does what DateJS does, only it's smaller, doesn't modify `Date.prototype`, and works in both the browser and NodeJS.

```
npm install moment
```

Usage:

```
moment(1316369911638).fromNow() // "3 minutes ago"
```

It supports i18n and customization as well, all strings are exposed for modification.

Comment: Note from the authors of moment.js: "_we would like to discourage Moment from being used in new projects going forward_" ([source](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)).

Answer (score 1):

I've found that `require(./date)` (i.e. using datejs directly) and datejs from `npm install datejs` don't work as advertised, at least with node v0.4.9.

The `datetime` module seems to work for me though:

```
$ npm install datetime
datetime@0.0.2 ./node_modules/datetime 
└── vows@0.5.8
$ node --version
v0.4.9
$ node
> var datetime = require('datetime')
> now = new Date()
Thu, 14 Jul 2011 05:50:06 GMT
> # wait for a bit
... 
... 
> datetime.formatAgo(now)
'18 seconds ago'
```